# Initializing javascript variables for repeating section in form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form with a repeating section that uses jQuery to clone the section and increment the ids. Now I need to initialize the variables in order to send the form via PHP.

HTML:

```
<div class="repeatingSection">
<label for="poste_1">Poste :</label>
<input type="text" name="poste_1" id="poste_1"/>
<label for="date_1">Date :</label>
<input type="text" name="date_1" id="date_1"/>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery('.cloneButton').click(function(event){

event.preventDefault();

var currentCount =  jQuery('.repeatingSection').length;
var newCount = currentCount+1;
var lastRepeatingGroup = jQuery('.repeatingSection').last();
var newSection = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(false).find('.cloneButton').remove().end();

newSection.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
newSection.find("input").each(function (index, input) {
    input.id = input.id.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
    input.name = input.name.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
});
newSection.find("label").each(function (index, label) {
    var l = jQuery(label);
    l.attr('for', l.attr('for').replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount));
});
return false;
});

jQuery(document.body).on('click','.removeButton', function(){

    jQuery(this).closest('div.repeatingSection').remove();
    return false;
});
```

PHP :

```
$poste1 = '';
$date1 = '';
$poste1 = trim($_POST['poste_1']);
$date1 = trim($_POST['date_1']);
```

I know I would need to put them in an array and loop through them but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and a count variable from javascript and do something like :

```
for($i=1; $i<$currentCount; $i++) { 
${"poste".$i} = trim($_POST["poste_$i"]);
${"date".$i} = trim($_POST["date_$i"]);
}
```

You would have variables $poste1 and $date1. Using ${''} creates dynamic variables.

Comment: Thank you. I won't be able to test it until I finish mucking through this form but I'll let you know.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is how I can use `$currentCount` a php variable when `var currentCount`is javascript. I must be missing something... Or do they have nothing to do with one another and I need to define `$currentCount`?

Comment: You can print out the javascript with php that way you can store what you like in a php variable or you can use AJAX (longer process)

Comment: I'm sorry but how could I print out the javascript with php?

Comment: I found the answer to my previous question (although I don't think I can do it because its Wordpress and everything has to be enqueued) but Even if I hardcode `$currentCount` I only get one set of values.